# Integer Programming - If then statement

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, minimization, maximize, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to linear/integer programming and I am having a hard time formulating constraints for a specific if-then statement in a fixed charge problem. Suppose that there are five manufacturers of t-shirts, and a customer wishes to purchase 400 t-shirts while minimizing costs.

| Producer | Variable cost/t-shirt | Delivery | Availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 40 | 200 |
| B | 3.5 | 30 | 100 |
| C | 4.10 | Free delivery | 100 |
| D | 4.1 | 30 | 200 |
| E | 3.2 | 30 | First 100 t-shirts |
| E | 2.90 | 20 | 101st-150th t-shirt |

Producer E has an availability of 150 t-shirts. The first 100 t-shirts bought from producer E have a variable cost of $3.20 and a delivery fee of $30. If the customer orders more than 100 t-shirts from producer E, she can buy them at a variable cost of $2.90 and an additional fee of $20.

How can I create constraints from this if-then statement:

- Xe1 = number of expensive t-shirts bought at producer E
- Xe2 = number of cheap t-shirts bought at producer E

I want constraint Xe2 <= 0 to exist when Xe1 < 100.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since Xe1 and Xe2 are both non-negative integer variables, your constraint is the same as `Xe1 <= 99 ⇒ Xe2 = 0`. This can be formulated as follows:

```
                b1 <= b2
99*b1 + 100*(1-b1) <= Xe1 <= 99*b1 + M*(1-b1)
             1-b2  <= Xe2 <= M'*(1-b2)
```

where `b1,b2` are binary helper variables and `M` and `M'` are upper bounds for `Xe1` and `Xe2`, i.e. `M = 101` and `M' = 400`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard "discount pricing model" where a discount price is awarded at a certain quantity.  You can introduce 1 binary variable to the model to do this.  This sounds like a H/W assignment.... :)

Let:

```
Xe1 be the qty bought from E at price 1
Xe2 be the qty bought from E at price 2
Ye be the decision to buy at the second price point y ∈ {0, 1}
Me2 be the qty available at the 2nd price (or a reasonable upper bound)
```

Then:

```
Xe2 <= Ye * Me2          # purchase at 2nd price point held to zero, unless Ye==1
Xe1 >= 100 * Ye          # Ye can only be 1 if 100 are purchased at Xe1
```

There are some nuances here with the shipping.  It isn't clear from the problem description if you bought 101 shirts from E if the shipping cost would be 30 + 20 (which would be odd) or the whole cost of shipping drops to 20.  You could use the same indicator variable `Ye` to work something out for that as well.